# Eclipse stops responding to most keyboard input after some amount of time/specific actions

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse

For some time now, it seems like Eclipse will stop responding to keystrokes (via any entry point of the app -- text editor, menus, etc...) if I switch between workspaces too many times. In some cases, it will resume responding after a bit of time.

I've had it suggested to me that it could be a memory paging problem, and as a suggested fix to change the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options to 512m. This doesn't seem to work.

Curiously, I don't have the same problem on the same machine in Windows 7.

I'm running Eclipse Indigo with Android DT plugin, Ubuntu 11.04, though I'm pretty sure earlier versions of both Eclipse and Ubuntu have exhibited the same behavior in my experience.

Below are my `eclipse.ini` and a dump of the `top` command. The memory noted below seems a little troubling but I assumed that was the result of my eclipse.ini setting.

What is my problem, and if it is simply a memory problem, what are ways I could get it under control? The machine I'm working with has a measly 2gb of RAM. Sorry for any cluelessness, but I am quite clueless when it comes to mucking with the internals of Eclipse. :)

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP COMMAND                                                  
5793 [user]    20   0  980m 299m  37m S    0 14.9   0:15.46 680m eclipse
```

Comment: Could it be that your whole comp ran out of memory?

Comment: Try with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659 and see if it helps

Comment: To soandos: That could be it, but if it were the whole computer, I would expect to see symptoms exhibited by the whole computer. So far, it's just been eclipse. @VonC I'll try out this eclipse.ini for a while and see if it helps, thanks!

Comment: @VonC No luck with these eclipse.ini changes. I will note though that I managed to use Eclipse for a day's work without issue if I did not use Ubuntu's workspace switcher, though I'd be hard pressed to know what the connection is. I'm going to look for ways to cut down on Ubuntu's memory usage and see if it helps.

Comment: @OEP: ok, it was worth a try anyway.

Comment: I'm having this same issue (Eclipse Indigo, Ubuntu Oneiric). I realize this question is old but I'm hoping someone has found an answer by now (especially because this question is a top Google result for this problem).